# Value error encountered when using index() function

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
mylist=[5,12,16,17,12]
index=mylist.index(3)
print(index)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: 3 is not in list
```

I am trying to find the value output at position 3 but I do not understand the error message why it says '3' is not in list.
From my understanding, the argument passed to index() will just be the element position. In this case, there is an element in position '3' i.e 17.
Need advice on helping to understand the error message. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common

Comment: Set index=mylist[3] instead. Index looks for if the number 3 is in the list and posts its position, the square brackets does the opposite, it looks for the position and posts the item in that position.

Answer (score 4):

The `index` function doesn't get the value at a specific index. It looks for a value and returns the index where it's found. Or throws an exception if the value isn't found.

If you want to get the fourth element in the list use "array" index syntax, like `mylist[3]`.

[This tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) explains it.

Answer (score 2):

The `index` function gives the position of the element you are looking for.
index=mylist.index(3) means you are looking for the position of element(3), which is not in `mylist` hence giving an error.

Now come to your question,
to find the element at particular position use mylist[index(an integer)].
So to find the element at 3rd position use `mylist[3]`.

for basics follow [indexing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 0):

The *index()* function of a list searches the list for the value passed as its parameter. If found, it will return the appropriate index (base 0). If not found, a ValueError exception will be raised. You are searching *mylist* for a value of 3 which doesn't exist - hence the exception. You probably meant *mylist[3]*